# Sidebar and main content centered in the window without being in the same parent container

Tags: css, mediawiki

I'm editing a MediaWiki site that uses the [Vector](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Vector) skin (the same used by Wikipedia and the MediaWiki official website itself). This skin has a sidebar of fixed width and a main content of resizable width that fills the rest of the window. I need to apply a fixed width to the main content and position both elements floating in the center of the window next to each other. The problem is that I can't simply apply a "margin: 0 auto;" to the parent container because they are not in the same container, the skin has a structure like:

```
<body>
  <div id="content" class="mw-body"></div> // Main content
  <div id="mw-navigation">
    <div id="mw-head"> // Header
    <div id="mw-panel"> // Sidebar
  </div>
  <div id="footer"> // Footer
</body>
```

Then they are positioned using position: absolute; but I don't know how to do what I want without the design getting completely distorted as the window resizes. I also tried to apply the widths and margins to the body, but the browser completely ignored the styles. How can I do this with pure CSS without touching the core of the skin? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Sorry for not adding a fiddle, but as I provided a link to the skin itself I didn't think it was necessary. Well, this is the basic current structure of the skin:

https://jsfiddle.net/gg2dv8g9/

And I need to do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/gg2dv8g9/1/

But the second fiddle requires the use a parent container, which the skin doesn't have, and which I can't add because I'm only allowed to modify the CSS.

Comment: Could you please provide the tried out fiddle so that it will be helpful to explain

Comment: Is the use of `positioning` manadatory...there are much more flexible layout methods?

Comment: @SaiDeepak Thanks for the suggestion, I've added the fiddle now.

Comment: @Paulie_D Unfortunately, the skin is structured in that way, so that's what I'm forced to work with. :/

Comment: Can you not use the `body` as the parent? - https://jsfiddle.net/gg2dv8g9/2/

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, I can. The problem came from another side because the skin I was modifying was not the pure Vector skin but it already had other modifications. Mainly, I was missing a position relative in the body and the background image made it seem like if the browser was ignoring the styles; but in short, I simply had to apply the margin auto and max-width to the body with a position relative and move the background image to the html tag. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't simply apply your `max-width` to the `body` tag and set its `margin` to `auto`,  you can achieve what you want using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ([See also](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)). I'm also assuming the `div` you labelled as the header is the page header and should appear at the top of the page so I've provided some positioning for that in the code below for you. Don't forget to [prefix the properties below as necessary](http://caniuse.com/).

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
body{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  padding:50px;
  position:relative;
}
#mw-head{
  background:#000;
  height:50px;
  left:50%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  transform:translatex(-50%);
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
}
#content{
  background:#f00;
  flex:0 1 calc(100% - 100px);
  height:100px;
  max-width:400px;
}
#mw-navigation{
  background:#0f0;
  flex:0 1 100px;
}
#footer{
  background:#000;
  page-break-before:always;
  break-before:always;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="mw-navigation">
  <div id="mw-head"></div>
  <div id="mw-panel"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: If the OP is using absolute positioning (as indicated) flexbox would have no effect.

Comment: Thank you! I realized what was my mistake but this answer certainly helped me.